# How to stop Django/PSQL from auto-incrementing table ID on creation failure

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psql

Currently, I have a Django project with an `ItemReport` table that only allows for 1 entry per day per item. Everything is fine and all except that whenever it fails with an IntegrityError (i.e. my project tried to create an `ItemReport` on a day when an `ItemReport` already exists, the object ID increments anyway.

For example:

```
September 1:
 Report for September 1 (ID 1)

September 2:
 Report for September 1 (ID 1)
 Report for September 2 (ID 5)
```

Models as follows:

```
class ItemReport(BaseModel):
    fk_item: Item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(default=now, null=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('fk_item', 'date'),)


class Item(BaseModel):
    item_class = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True, null=False)
```

Bit of code that gets run everytime a user logs in:

```
    for i in Item.objects.all():
        try:
            latest_ir = ItemReport.objects.create(fk_item=i)
            print('Created Item Report!')
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print('ItemReport for {} for today already exists!'.format(i.name))
    print('Created ItemReports!\n')
```

Comment: Don't rely on the IDs being any particular values. They should be completely unrelated to your business logic.

Comment: So you're saying using IDs in logic is bad practice? I was going to use them as a means to make sure tables are synced properly between servers. If not by IDs then, any ideas on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three years after you asked the question, I've had the same issue and finding out this is not answered in SO yet, I would like to leave here how I solved the problem for future visitors.

Previously, I used below code in order to prevent duplicate errors.

```
try:
    m = Modal(title='Title', content='Content.')
    m.save()
except IntegrityError:
    pass
```

But I had the same problem as you, whenever it fails with an `IntegrityError` the object ID was incrementing anyway.

I solved the issue by removing `try/except` block and using `get_or_create()` instead of `save()`.

```
Modal.objects.get_or_create(title='Title', content='Content.')
```

Detailed explanation of the `get_or_create()` method in the Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: When using a constraint in the model on two or more fields, get_or_create will try and create a new object and increase the PK and the contstraint will return an IntegrityError.

So, in a way, this just solves a problem if everything in the form/serializer is an exact duplicate of an already existing object in the DB. You're still going to need to try/except the IntegrityError from the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it if pk is auto increment field. When you try to create new object, data base get value form sequence. And sequence does not support rollback, because when many user insert new rows at the same time, and only one is aborted, for rebuild sequence, you need many hard operation inside database.

hope it help you.

Comment: I see. I didn't know it worked that way. So if I understood correctly, setting the field to not-auto increment would fix the issue?

Comment: i think you need extra field for logic that will be not auto increment